# A simple question about def function (if word starts with "pre" return "valid)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a functio to ask people to enter a word, if it starts with "pre" return "valid", otherwise print "not valid".

```
def word_fun(word):
    word = input("enter a word: ").lower()
    if word.startswith("pre") and word.isalpha:
        print("valid")
    else:
        print("not valid")
word_fun(word)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You aren't calling `word.isalpha`; you are just confirming that `word.isalpha` is bound to a truthy value (which it is, since `word` is a `str`).

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

That code produces the error `NameError: name 'word' is not defined`.  That means that you're using the variable `word` in a scope where it isn't defined yet. This is happening on the last line, where you call the function.

You can fix this by removing the parameter from your function, since it isn't needed. Remove it from both the definition and the call.

```
def word_fun():
    word = input("enter a word: ").lower()
    if word.startswith("pre") and word.isalpha():
        print("valid")
    else:
        print("not valid")

word_fun()
```

Note: I also fixed `word.isalpha()`, as mentioned by chepner in the comment to your question.